# Replace Insides of Old Leaky Push/Pull Tub Valve

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, bathroom-fixtures

I have a leaky push/pull shower/tub valve that caused some wall damage.  I have taken off the outer components but I can't see any obvious way to open the valve so that I can replace the insides, similar to what can be done on newer valves.

Is this even possible or will I need to bring out a plumber to replace the entire valve?

I did notice on the bottom of the outer ring where the valve protrudes, the ring is not complete, but has a small gap along it's length which allows me to pull it apart laterally, though I haven't done that with any significant amount of force for fear of causing irreparable damage.

We're not ready to remodel otherwise I'd replace the old plumbing, so I'm looking for advice on how to fix this in the cheapest easiest manner.

[image][image][image]

Comment: The metal piece on the front should pull off, and then the chrome sleeve around everything else slides off.

Comment: If I pull the metal piece in front it opens the valve.  I haven't tried that with the water off though so I'll give that a shot next.  Thanks for the suggestion.